# How to write jpa query using Like ,between and enum?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

How to write jpa query in java

```
public class Record{

string id;
string senderId;
string reciverId;
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private RecordType recordType;
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private RecordStatus recordStatus;
@Column(name = "transfer_date", columnDefinition = "DATE")
Date transferDate;
}
```

**Here is JPA Query I tried.**

```
@Query("select r from Record r where (t.transferDate BETWEEN ?1 AND ?2 ) and (senderId = ?3 or reciverId = ?4) and status =?5 AND r.recordType Like ?6")


  List<TransactionBean> findByTransferDateBetweenAndReciverIdOrSenderIdAndRecordStatusAndRecordType(Date fromDate,Date toDate, String senderId, String reciverId, RecordStatus status, String recordType);
```

findByTransferDateBetweenAndReciverIdOrSenderIdAndRecordStatusAndRecordType(fromDate,toDate,"1","1",RecordStatus.COMPLETE,"ONLINE");

**EnumType**

```
ONLINE_TO_ONLINE,
OFFLINE_TO_OFFLINE,
ONLINE_TO_OFFLINE,
OFFLINE_TO_ONLINE
```

For me getting always empty.Any one can help ?

Answer (score 0):

You are directly passing the enum to the query, modify to pass it as string. Try something like this.

```
@Query("select r from Record r where (t.transferDate BETWEEN ?1 AND ?2 ) and (senderId = ?3 or reciverId = ?4) and status =?5 r.recordType Like ?6")
List<TransactionBean> findByTransferDateBetweenAndReciverIdOrSenderIdAndRecordStatusAndRecordType(Date fromDate,Date toDate, String senderId, String reciverId, RecordStatus status, String recordType);
```

change `RecordStatus status` parameter to `String recordStatus` and pass the value to the parameter of this method `findByTransferDateBetweenAndReciverIdOrSenderIdAndRecordStatusAndRecordType()` like this.

```
RecordStatus.COMPLETE.toString()
```

Changed code.

```
@Query("select r from Record r where (t.transferDate BETWEEN ?1 AND ?2 ) and (senderId = ?3 or reciverId = ?4) and status =?5 r.recordType Like ?6")
List<TransactionBean> findByTransferDateBetweenAndReciverIdOrSenderIdAndRecordStatusAndRecordType(Date fromDate,Date toDate, String senderId, String reciverId, String recordStatus, String recordType);
```

your calling method look like this.

```
findByTransferDateBetweenAndReciverIdOrSenderIdAndRecordStatusAndRecordType("", "", "", "", RecordStatus.COMPLETE.toString(), "");
```

if your enum has values then you need to use constuructor to get the values. for example

```
RecordStatus.COMPLETE.getValue()
```

Comment: Here I tried with enum without like ,All is working fine  ,while using like operator it not able to filter,I thought sending string value is not good

Myquestion is simple how can we get values using like

Comment: you missed the % sign in like if that's what you are referring. `LIKE '%value%'` this is how you normally use like to search.